# How to override a function of the plugin class in wordpress funcation.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have class like bellow in one of my plugin.

```
class MyClass {
public function __construct() {
      add_action( 'wp',array( $this, 'getStuffDone' ) );
 }
 public function getStuffDone() {
      // .. This is where stuff gets done ..
 }
```

}

i want to override function "getStuffDone" with my custom code. is it possible to do that in funcation.php? If yes how would i do that. please help.

Thank you.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157343/is-it-possible-to-override-this-function-class-in-a-child-theme

Comment: this is widget function and  it's overriding theme function i have different problem. i want to ovrride a plugin function.

Comment: Yes. you can do the same

Comment: use wp instead of widget

Comment: Is it possible to give detail answer as i don't know how to do it in funcation.php what should i write in place of $this and all that.

Comment: please let me know excat action of plugin add_action( 'wp'

Comment: excat action? means

Comment: exact action of plugin. Is it wp action?

Comment: Yes sir. it is wp action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128425/discussion-between-user2105662-and-vel).

Comment: Try to remove the action thrown by the class:

    remove_action('wp', array('MyClass', 'getStuffDone'));